# Matplotlib define array from text file

Tags: matplotlib

So I am trying figure out how to read a text file and plot values from it... I have a text file which is updated every 5 seconds and values are written like this:

```
"Day, Time, channel1, channel2, channel3, channel4"
```

Each line is a new 5 second stamp of data.

I want to plot an animated graph of 4 lines (channel1 - channel4) which all
share the same x-axis value... how do I define this? below is the pertinent code
thus far...

```
#MATPLOTLIB ANIMATED GRAPH
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


ln1, = ax1.plot([], [], 'r-')
ln2, = ax1.plot([], [], 'g-')
ln3, = ax1.plot([], [], 'b-')
ln4, = ax1.plot([], [], 'p-')

def animate(i):
    pullData = open("%s.txt" % FILE_NAME,"r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)&gt;1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            ln1.set_data(x1, y1)
            ln2.set_data(x1, y2)
            ln3.set_data(X1, y3)
            ln4.set_data(x1, y4)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(ln1)
    ax1.plot(ln2)
    ax1.plot(ln3)
    ax1.plot(ln4)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=5000)
plt.show()
```

How would I define the x and y for each individual line?

------ Edit #3 -----

```
import Queue
import datetime as DT
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from ABE_DeltaSigmaPi import DeltaSigma 
from ABE_helpers import ABEHelpers

i2c_helper = ABEHelpers() 
bus = i2c_helper.get_smbus() 
adc = DeltaSigma(bus, 0x68, 0x69, 18)

#Rename file to date
base_dir = '/home/pi/Desktop/DATA'
filename_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
filename_base = os.path.join(base_dir, filename_time)
filename = '%s.txt' % filename_base

# you will want to change read_delay to 5000
read_delay = int(5000)    # in milliseconds 
write_delay = read_delay/1000.0  # in seconds 
window_size = 60
nlines = 8
datenums = collections.deque(maxlen=window_size)
ys = [collections.deque(maxlen=window_size) for i in range(nlines)]

def animate(i, queue):
    try:
        row = queue.get_nowait()
    except Queue.Empty:
        return
    datenums.append(mdates.date2num(row[0]))
    for i, y in enumerate(row[1:]):
        ys[i].append(y)
    for i, y in enumerate(ys):
        lines[i].set_data(datenums, y)
    ymin = min(min(y) for y in ys)
    ymax = max(max(y) for y in ys)
    xmin = min(datenums)
    xmax = max(datenums)
    if xmin < xmax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
    fig.canvas.draw()

def write_data(filename, queue):
    while True:
        delay1 = DT.datetime.now()
        row = []
        for i in range(nlines):
            # read from adc channels and print to screen
            channel = adc.read_voltage(i)
            row.append(channel)

        queue.put([delay1]+row)

        #print voltage variables to local file
        with open(filename, 'a') as DAQrecording:
            time1 = delay1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            time2 = delay1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            row = [time1, time2] + row
            row = map(str, row)
            DAQrecording.write('{}\n'.format(', '.join(row)))

        #Delay until next 5 second interval
        delay2 = DT.datetime.now()
        difference = (delay2 - delay1).total_seconds()
        time.sleep(write_delay - difference)

def main():
    global fig, ax, lines
    queue = mp.Queue()
    proc = mp.Process(target=write_data, args=(filename, queue))
    # terminate proc when main process ends
    proc.daemon = True
    # spawn the writer in a separate process
    proc.start()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
    # make matplotlib treat x-axis as times
    ax.xaxis_date()

    fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=25)

    lines = []
    for i in range(nlines):
        line, = ax.plot([], [])
        lines.append(line)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=read_delay, fargs=(queue,))
    plt.show()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It would help to post some sample lines of data, since the format of `Day` and `Time` will affect the answer.

Comment: Sorry! here is a sample line:2015-01-06, 00:18:14, -0.0286875, -0.0004375, -0.0005, -0.0004375, -0.000375, -0.000375, -0.0004375, -0.000375    ...  I would be interested in plotting all lines, but I can muck around with the code once I get the basics down.  Time is in: HH:MM:SS, so yes that was 12:18:14 AM....

Comment: Do you want to read a line from the file once every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yeah... so basically, what I want is a graph that shows real time data that is being logged into the txt file. The txt file will be updated every 5 seconds with new readings from each channel. The infinite loop for read/write to file is after this section of code...Now, I am starting to think that the total amount of data points needing to plot every 5 seconds will be large over time (leave it running for 30 minutes would equal 2880 data points, split among 8 lines to plot). SO if it can even demonstrate the last 5 minutes of data (60 values per line) that would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work today, doing everything I need! Thanks for all your help. The final product can:

1. Display readouts from 8 analog sensors in one graph on left, refresh every 5 seconds, and only displays the last 5 minutes of data.
2. The right chart works as a white canvas, displaying the last values which have been read and graphed. I have not been able to figure out how to clear this every 5 seconds, so the text boxes have a white background which covers the old values.
3. All data is written and saved to a text file with date and time stamped with day (D/M/Y) and time (H:M:S).

For anyone else who may be interested in doing something like this, the code is below:

```
import Queue
import os
import sys
import datetime as DT
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from ABE_DeltaSigmaPi import DeltaSigma 
from ABE_helpers import ABEHelpers

i2c_helper = ABEHelpers() 
bus = i2c_helper.get_smbus() 
adc = DeltaSigma(bus, 0x68, 0x69, 16)

#Rename file to date
base_dir = '/home/pi/Desktop/DATA'
ts = time.time()
filename_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
filename_base = os.path.join(base_dir, filename_time)
filename = '%s.txt' % filename_base

# you will want to change read_delay to 5000
read_delay = int(5000)    # in milliseconds 
write_delay = read_delay/1000.0  # in seconds 
window_size = 60
nlines = 8
ypadding = 0.5
datenums = collections.deque(maxlen=window_size)
ys = [collections.deque(maxlen=window_size) for i in range(nlines)]

def animate(i, queue):
    try:
        row = queue.get_nowait()
    except Queue.Empty:
        return
    datenums.append(mdates.date2num(row[0]))
    for i, y in enumerate(row[1:]):
        ys[i].append(y)
    for i, y in enumerate(ys):
        lines[i].set_data(datenums, y)
    ymin1 = min(min(y) for y in ys)
    ymin = ymin1 - ypadding
    ymax1 = max(max(y) for y in ys)
    ymax = ymax1 + ypadding
    xmin = min(datenums)
    xmax = max(datenums)
    if xmin < xmax:
        ax1.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ax1.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)

    ax2.plot(0, 0)
    ax2.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax2.set_ylim(0, 1)
    channel1 = row[-8]
    channel2 = row[-7]
    channel3 = row[-6]
    channel4 = row[-5]
    channel5 = row[-4]
    channel6 = row[-3]
    channel7 = row[-2]
    channel8 = row[-1]

    ax2.text(0.1,0.8,'CH1: %.02f \n CH2: %.02f \n CH3: %.02f \n CH4: %.02f \n CH5: %.02f \n CH6: %.02f \n CH7: %.02f \n CH8: %.02f \n' % (channel1,channel2,channel3,channel4,channel5,channel6,channel7,channel8) , ha='left', va='top', backgroundcolor='w')
    fig.canvas.draw()

def write_data(filename, queue):
    while True:
        delay1 = DT.datetime.now()
        row = []
        for i in range(nlines):
            # read from adc channels and print to screen
            channel = adc.read_voltage(i)
            row.append(channel)

        queue.put([delay1]+row)

        #print voltage variables to local file
        with open(filename, 'a') as DAQrecording:
            time1 = delay1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            time2 = delay1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            row = [time1, time2] + row
            row = map(str, row)
            DAQrecording.write('{}\n'.format(', '.join(row)))

        #Delay until next 5 second interval
        delay2 = DT.datetime.now()
        difference = (delay2 - delay1).total_seconds()
        time.sleep(write_delay - difference)

def main():
    global fig, ax1, ax2, lines
    queue = mp.Queue()
    proc = mp.Process(target=write_data, args=(filename, queue))
    # terminate proc when main process ends
    proc.daemon = True
    # spawn the writer in a separate process
    proc.start()

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=False) 
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2, width_ratios=[3, 1] wspace=None)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
    ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
    ax2.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax2.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

    # make matplotlib treat x-axis as times
    ax1.xaxis_date()
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    fig.suptitle('Data Acquisition', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

    lines = []
    for i in range(nlines):
        line, = ax1.plot([], [])
        lines.append(line)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=read_delay, fargs=(queue,))
    plt.show()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing and reading from the same file would require a lock to prevent a race condition -- reading from a file before it is fully written. It's possible, but below I suggest a different way.

Since both programs are written in Python, you could use the multiprocessing module to spawn the writer process, and have it write values to a Queue.
Then the main process can have `animate` get values from the Queue and draw the result. Queue handles the locking and interprocess communication for us, and allows us to transfer the datetime object and float values *as Python objects* without having to read them from a file and parse the strings.

```
import Queue
import datetime as DT
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.animation as animation
try:
    from ABE_DeltaSigmaPi import DeltaSigma 
    from ABE_helpers import ABEHelpers
    i2c_helper = ABEHelpers() 
    bus = i2c_helper.get_smbus() 
    adc = DeltaSigma(bus, 0x68, 0x69, 18)
except ImportError:
    class ADC(object):
        """
        This is a dummy class to mock the adc.read_voltage calls.
        """
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 0
        def read_voltage(self, i):
            if i == 0:
                self.x += 0.1
            return np.sin(self.x/10)*(i+1)

    adc = ADC()

filename = 'data.txt'
# you will want to change read_delay to 5000
read_delay = int(0.05 * 1000)    # in milliseconds 
write_delay = read_delay/1000.0  # in seconds 
window_size = 60
nlines = 8
datenums = collections.deque(maxlen=window_size)
ys = [collections.deque(maxlen=window_size) for i in range(nlines)]

def animate(i, queue):
    try:
        row = queue.get_nowait()
    except Queue.Empty:
        return
    datenums.append(mdates.date2num(row[0]))
    for i, y in enumerate(row[1:]):
        ys[i].append(y)
    for i, y in enumerate(ys):
        lines[i].set_data(datenums, y)
    ymin = min(min(y) for y in ys)
    ymax = max(max(y) for y in ys)
    xmin = min(datenums)
    xmax = max(datenums)
    if xmin < xmax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
    fig.canvas.draw()

def write_data(filename, queue):
    while True:
        delay1 = DT.datetime.now()
        row = []
        for i in range(nlines):
            # read from adc channels and print to screen
            channel = adc.read_voltage(i)
            temp = 3.45 * channel
            row.append(temp)

        queue.put([delay1]+row)

        #print voltage variables to local file
        with open(filename, 'a') as DAQrecording:
            time1 = delay1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            time2 = delay1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            row = [time1, time2] + row
            row = map(str, row)
            DAQrecording.write('{}\n'.format(', '.join(row)))

        #Delay until next 5 second interval
        delay2 = DT.datetime.now()
        difference = (delay2 - delay1).total_seconds()
        time.sleep(write_delay - difference)

def main():
    global fig, ax, lines
    queue = mp.Queue()
    proc = mp.Process(target=write_data, args=(filename, queue))
    # terminate proc when main process ends
    proc.daemon = True
    # spawn the writer in a separate process
    proc.start()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
    # make matplotlib treat x-axis as times
    ax.xaxis_date()

    fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=25)

    lines = []
    for i in range(nlines):
        line, = ax.plot([], [])
        lines.append(line)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=read_delay, fargs=(queue,))
    plt.show()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: awesome! will try this and see.... can you explain to me the class ADC(object)? Will this basically cycle through channels 1-8?

Comment: I don't have your `adc` (module?), so I created a class `ADC` to simulate what `adc.read_voltage` might return. Since you have `adc` defined, you can remove the `try...import adc..except...` and just replace it with `import adc` if `adc` is a module.

Comment: Here is the module inputs for my adc module; "from ABE_DeltaSigmaPi import DeltaSigma from ABE_helpers import ABEHelpers" and then to read the value, its call is 'adc.read_voltage()'. Basically if I add the above import modules it should be golden??

Comment: In theory yes. Try it and see! Somewhere you also have to define `adc`.

Comment: ok I added and it worked, but see me edits/comment above - THANKS for all your help thus far!!!

Comment: evidently, my comment didnt work... it prints to a file, but the channels are constantly increasing in voltage... which isnt the case when I use my older read/write version... can you see what might be doing this? here is a link to text file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d016qyk89q88tpb/data.txt?dl=0

Comment: The beginning of `data.txt` appears to include some sinusoidal data, maybe left over from running my code above using the ADC class. You may want to remove the ADC class entirely so there is no chance that code is getting run. Remember also that `open(filename, 'a')` opens the file in `append` mode, so you should delete the file if you want to get rid of the sinusoidal data generated by the ADC class. I have no idea why the latter part of `data.txt` is constantly increasing. If you post the code you are running I'll take a look.

Comment: I ran the code you supplied, just changed the delay to 5 seconds... The first portion of the data would have been before I switched it to 5 second read/write delay.

Comment: Oh, in that case, you are just looking at a sine wave being generated really slowly. You need to define `adc` *as you did in your original code* if you wish to see data like your original code. I can't help you there because you haven't posted how `adc` was originally defined.

Comment: Gotcha! sorry, my experience in python is rather limited so I am learning as I go. the code to return a voltage is: adc.read_voltage(x), were x is the channel.  so if I simply list adc.read_voltage(1), adc.read_voltage(2)... this will work? Sorry I didn't catch the 'Dummy variable"

Comment: Remove the block of lines that starts with `try:` and ends with `adc = ADC()`. Replace them with your definition of `adc`. I can't tell you what to put here because you haven't given any hint in anything you posted as to what that might be. But it must be in your original code, since you managed to get it to run. I suggest looking for lines that begin with `adc = `, or `import adc`, or `from some_module import *` (which is a very bad practice, by the way). Note that you do **not** need to use or change `adc.read_voltage` here; that call can stay as it is in the code below.

Comment: I think I understand... would I be able to simple delete from 'except ImportError" .... to "adc = ADC()", since their will not be an import error? omitting the 'in case reading'. 'adc' is part of the ABE_DeltaSigmaPi module. so if I say ' print adc.read_voltage(1)' I will get a print out of the voltage through channel 1 in console. which was the basics of my initial code.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I forgot this: "i2c_helper = ABEHelpers()
bus = i2c_helper.get_smbus()
adc = DeltaSigma(bus, 0x68, 0x69, 18)"
 Which is present after the import lines.

Comment: Yes! Now you're cooking!

Comment: I now just changed the code so that it can automatically rename files based on day. This is lets me know what day corresponds to the data (provided the Pi has a proper date/time). My next (and hopefully final) question, if I wanted to incorporate an equation to calculate temperature from the voltages (I.E. temp = 3.45 * channel1, channel1 = adc.read_voltage(1) )... then subsequently graph them and write to file? Thanks thus far unutbu, I am really loving the capabilities of python!!

Comment: That change is very easy to make; I've edited the post to show how. I know that I am robbing you of the opportunity to learn by doing -- which is a necessary skill for all programmers -- but I hope this example will help show you the basics so you can do more learning by doing on your own in the future.

Comment: This example has taught me so much in a couple days! honestly, that was an extremely easy change. I am/was unfamiliar with 'for i in range(nlines)' but now it all makes complete sense. Still a little to understand from matplotlib but I have a learnt a tonne already! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to change the absolute size (in pixels, height/width) of the graph? I am also looking at having the values 'print' every 5 seconds. So I am trying to have the graph take up some space while the values are printed either below or to the right... my max screen size is 650 x 500 (W x H). A simply console print of them is fine... just gotta figure out how to get the console to open up below/beside graph.

Comment: Well, I think I can answer the first part: Use something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=300)` to control the absolute size of the graph. The figsize is given in inches, and `dpi` specifies the number of dots per inch. Sorry, I don't know the answer to the second part. I see [you've asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28012876/190597) about it. That's good, but you may need to make a **minimal** example to make it easier for others to run and understand. That will increase the amount of help you get and its applicability to others facing a similar situation.

Comment: O.K.! I can definitely get the dimensions portion to work... Is there a way to display maybe something below or beside the matplotlib canvas? Basically a 'print' of the rows new values every five seconds?

Comment: I think I might have a solution, could I simply use a legend, but then have each line for the legend refresh every five seconds to display the channel input?? basically row[1] = line 1, etc.... any idea how I could write this up?

Comment: here is the Legend argument, fig.legend( (Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4,) , ('ADC output 1', 'ADC output 2', 'ADC output 3', etc), 'location' ). I tried using enumerate(lines[1]) since this would come after argument lines = [] for i in range(nlines), which didnt work... any suggested solutions? This would be the easiest way - if I can figure out how to get y values to print to legend argument...

Comment: I think I have a solution. Would you be able to help me by adding a second small graph to the left of this one that doesn't display anything, basically a white canvas to the right? I can write the channel values here as 'ax.text(0,1, channel1,ha=x, va=x)'. I got it to work on the main graph but since it cycles, the text moves leftword :( ... hopefully you get what I am trying to accomplish! Thanks in advance

Comment: I have had huge success with this code... however I am finding that there is a lag in display over time... which gets progressively longer... The writing of the file is fine, its the plot(s) which become slower than actual realtime drawing... do you know why/how to fix that?